# Passing data from view to model in model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm reading data from my view. And I need to pass data to controller via model. But the problem is that I need to pass data to model in model.

I've tried this one

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(item.ItemCount, null, new { @class="input_quantity- 
    value", value = "2.5", data_type="area", data_width="2.5"})
}
```

but this is incorrect

Here's my code for view

```
@model TechnoTent.Models.ViewModel.OrderVM

@using (Html.BeginForm("EditOrder", "AdminOrder", FormMethod.Post, new { 
@class = "product-edit", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(item.ItemCount, null, new { 
        @class="input_quantity-value", value = "2.5", data_type="area", data_width="2.5"})
    }
}
```

Here code for controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditOrder(OrderVM order)
{
    AdminOrders.EditOrder(order);

    return View();
 }
```

and here's a part of code for my model

```
 public class OrderVM
 {
     public List<OrderItemsVM> Items { get; set; }
 }
```

and here's a part of code for my OrderItemsVM model

```
 public class OrderItemsVM
 {
      public string ItemCount { get; set; }
 }
```

I need to read ItemCount from a view to my OrderItemsVm. Is it possible somehow? or better to have a List in a base model and to read it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change below code in views

> cshtml page

```
    @model TechnoTent.Models.ViewModel.OrderVM

    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditOrder", "AdminOrder", FormMethod.Post, new { 
    @class = "product-edit", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()        
        for(int i=0; i < Model.Items.Count;i++)
        {
@Html.TextBox("Items["+i+"].ItemCount", "2.5", new { 
            @class="input_quantity-value", value = "2.5", data_type="area", data_width="2.5"})
        }
    }
```

> cshtml page if you want set model values in controller like you are editing the data

```
    @model TechnoTent.Models.ViewModel.OrderVM

    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditOrder", "AdminOrder", FormMethod.Post, new { 
    @class = "product-edit", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()        
        for(int i=0; i < Model.Items.Count;i++)
        {
@Html.TextBox("Items["+i+"].ItemCount",Model.Items[i].ItemCount , new { 
            @class="input_quantity-value", value = "2.5", data_type="area", data_width="2.5"})
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me.

Comment: Welcome, Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your controller and view models look fine to me. This is how I would do the views. First add a folder "EditorTemplates" inside the Views folder. Then create OrderItemsVM.cshtml view inside that folder.

/EditorTemplates/OrderItemsVM.cshtml:

```
@model TechnoTent.Models.ViewModel.OrderItemsVM

<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ItemCount, new { @class = "..." })
</div>
```

In your form page, get rid of @foreach(...){...} block and replace it with @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Items)

YourFormPage.cshtml:

```
@model TechnoTent.Models.ViewModel.OrderVM

@using (Html.BeginForm(...))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Items)
    ...
}
```